# Detecting if an element "overlaps" isn't working in MS Edge browser

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

**Context -**
I have built an Angular 6 directive to handle long text. It does following things -

If HTML element is overflowing then truncate the text content via CSS class and on hover of an element showing tooltip where full text is displayed.

I don't want to show tooltip on those element which are not overflowing, that's why conditionally checking if an element is overflowing or not.

I have created a function `isOverflow` which looks for a difference in element's height or width to identify if element overflows.

If the difference is `0` then it is not overflowing and if it has some value then it is overflowing.

This logic works fine in Chrome and Firefox but not in MS Edge browser -

```
element.offsetHeight - element.scrollHeight;
element.offsetWidth - element.scrollWidth;
```

In MS Edge browser the difference is always `0` .

How to programmatically (javascript) find out in MS Edge browser if an element is overflowing?

Comment: This very much smells of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), why do you need this?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that reproduces the problem